# rails date validation with age

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

In my rails application there's a signup form which includes a DOB field.
The user's age need not to be more than 18.How can i give validation for this one.

My dob format is mm/dd/yy

Comment: are you looking for front-end validation, or activerecord validation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax for this is pretty fun, you could do something like this:

```
old_enough = ("10/23/2000".to_date + 18.years) < Date.today
```

Turn your string into a date, add 18 years, and see if it is before or after today.

If you want to put this in a model validator, this railscast could be useful:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3

Answer (score 8):

You can do the validation yourself. Convert the string to a date with `to_date` and check that it's less than `18.years.ago`.

Put that check in a method in your user model, and have it call something like `errors.add :dob, 'must be older than 18'` if it fails.

Then at the top of your model call `validates :dob_check`