# Rails date validation with conditional validation if and future? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I found a few duplicate Q&As; however, I did not figure it out.

I have `House` model which has `:available_at` validation (The field is `Date`). I'm trying to achieve something like this.

> The availability date must be in future.

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "houses", force: :cascade do |t|
  # ...
  t.date "available_at", null: false
  # ...
end

# app/models/house.rb
class House < ApplicationRecord
  validates :available_at, presence: true, if: -> { available_at.future? }
end
```

Also, here is the [PR](https://github.com/BerkhanBerkdemir/magara/pull/12)

---

Duplicate answers
[Conditional Validation RAILS MODEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729695/conditional-validation-rails-model)
[Conditional validation if another validation is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080432/conditional-validation-if-another-validation-is-valid)
[Rails validate uniqueness only if conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914899/rails-validate-uniqueness-only-if-conditional)
[rails date validation with age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998151/rails-date-validation-with-age)
[How do I validate a date in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597328/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-rails)
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110262/checking-for-valid-date-range-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for [Mark Merritt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4988918/mark-merritt) because I inspired his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992715/8929392). The answer works as expected, but the problem is keeping the model DRY, and also, it has a long method name.

I created separate validator which is name `at_future_validator.rb`. I placed the file inside of `lib/validators` folder.

Then, I wrote this validator

```
# lib/validators/at_future_validator.rb
class AtFutureValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if attribute.present? && value < Date.today
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'must be in the future')
    end
  end
end
```

OK. The first part has done. The important part is, which I saw now on the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations), working with custom validator which we named `at_future_validator`. We need to require the validator inside of the `house` model.

```
# app/models/house.rb
class House < ApplicationRecord
  require_dependency 'validators/at_future_validator'
  # ...
  validates :available_at, presence: true, at_future: true
  # ...
end
```

---

Guides that I followed
[#211 Validations in Rails 3 - 8:09](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3?autoplay=true)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use case for a custom method that validates available_at...

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  validate :available_at_is_in_the_future

  def available_at_is_in_the_future
    if available_at.present? && available_at <= Date.today
      errors.add(:available_at, "must be in the future")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For now, it works like charm, but I need to update RSpecs. After that I will mark as answer.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I added my answer. You can check it out!

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the point is that model should do model's job.